# Question on time of collision and relative velocities (Answer verification)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, collision, relative-motion

I was doing this question which I found quiet alright, however after checking the answer, I wasn't very sure if my method was alright. The question is:

A ship P has position $-11i+j$ km relative to a light house $O$. At the same time the position of a boat Q relative to the light house was $4i-13j$ km. The velocity of P is $3i$ and the velocity of Q is $xj$.($i$ and $j$ are the orthogonal unit vectors)

If they are on collision course, find x and the time at which collision occurs.

My approach was as follows:

The position of P : $-11i + j + 3ti = (3t-11)i+j$, where $t$ is the time

The position of Q : $4i-13j+xtj =4i + (xt-13)j$

At collison the position vectors will be equal Therefore we have,

$(3t-11)i + j = 4i + (xt-13)j$

By equating coefficients, we have

$$3t-11 = 4$$
$$t = 5$$

And,

$$xt-13 =1$$
$$5x -13 =1$$
$$x = \frac{14}{5}$$

Is this the correct way of calculating the time of collision of two objects, knowing about their position vectors relative to a point as well as their relative velocities?

Comment: Hi BasemFouda. In addition to our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583), please also note that we consider most variants of [check-my-work questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) off-topic.